# How can I see all debugging information in Salesforce?

Tags: debugging, salesforce, apex

I am working on my first Salesforce Apex/Visualforce app. I am new to Salesforce. I am frustrated with my inability to see data in the Developer Console.

I have this code:

```
public SearchResult__c saveProfileResult(String privco_data) {
    SearchResult__c sr = new SearchResult__c();
    Object deserializedObject = deserializeJson(privco_data);

    if (deserializedObject != null) {
        List<Object> dataList = (List<Object>)deserializeJson(privco_data);
        System.debug(dataList); 
        Map<String, Object> profileMap = (Map<String, Object>)dataList[0];
        System.debug('profileMap:');
        System.debug(profileMap);
    Set<String> profileKeys = profileMap.keySet(); 
    System.debug(profileKeys);      
    Map<String, Object> address = (Map<String, Object>)profileMap.get('address');
```

I need to see what is in profileKeys. But the debug statement is only showing me:

```
17:28:19:968 USER_DEBUG [115]|DEBUG|{address, company_registration_number, company_type, country_incorp, general_counsel, industry, name, permalink, profile_classification, profile_id, ...}
```

How do I see the rest of it? I need to see all of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

When you see Execution log in Developer console you can just double click on row with interesting for you debug information, so you will see popup with full detail message.

Also, if you want to modify logging level settings, go to Setup -> Administration Setup -> Monitoring -> Debug Logs, and setup log trace level which you need.

Comment: What I've posted in this StackExchange question is what I see after I double-clicked on the entry in the log. That is what surprises me so much. When I double click on a log entry, it opens in a new window, but it contains no additional information. It is still cut off at the same point.